# Hi, i'm using spool for exporting 6 millions records, is query executes once or till end of last record

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2, spool

A view returns 6 millions records.
Earlier i used to export with sql developer(right click and export, it takes more than 2hr), but my senior said that, if do like this query will get executes every 500 rows. so we are getting warnings from DBA(long running queries).

when searching internet i found that spooling works better for exporting. So i have doubt,In spooling is query executes once & start exporting or it executes for till last row exporting.

Comment: I mean query executes once and start exporting or it cont to execute till last record

Comment: please edit and update the question with correct sentence and bit of more details

Comment: hi amit any answer

Comment: your question is hard to understand. did you already use sql developer successfully to export the 6 millions rows?

Comment: Why do you export these rows?

Comment: we need to export every week. and Sql developer is taking more than 3hrs to export, so we need to optimize the time

Answer (score 1):

it is executed once, create a cursor which is the image of your query at the time of the execution, and then start fetching your data in your spool. 
If you make any update after the execution, it will not appear in your spool.